# Wireless Printer not found to set up printer when wireless printer is connected in 14.10 upgrade

Tags: wireless, networking, printing, 14.10

I just upgraded from  14.04 to 14.10 32 bit.  I was using my wireless printer with 14.04 with no problem.  But after the upgrade, my printer area doesn't see the wireless printer to print to.  I can hook it up direct and it prints fine, but I use the wireless printer from other places in the apartment.  My printer is HP-Deskjet-3050A-J611-series and there is a Linux driver which I downloaded and installed, no problem.  It just doesn't show up on the list of available printers to print to now when the wireless is on and connected. Why won't it show up with 14.10 when it was there with 14.04?  Am I going to have to revert back to 14.04 to use the wireless function to print?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here was what happened.  The new firewall setting hadn't set the wireless connection to the printer as trusted.  Once it was set to trusted, the printer showed up and set up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok..Thank you so much...that was a useful piece of info...

Answer (score 0):

While you upgrade your machine from  14.04 to 14.10 packages which was referring the wireless printer would get differed and this is reason it was not showing your wireless printer.

Reinstall your printer which may fix this issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I reinstalled the printer software but it still doesn't show on the list of printers available to add like it did with 14.04.